# If a checkbox is checked, find how many user input values are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a script that reveals a user input if a checkbox is checked. The user input is designed to place a value that links it to other div's. The same input means it is in the same group of div's.

How could I find out how many unique values are input by the user after they have checked the checkbox?

As a bonus, if I can discover which master div's these inputs and checkboxes belong to that would be great.

Thanks,
Eamon

---

UPDATE:

The rough html that is repeated would be:

```
<div class="master">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

The text input would only be revealed if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Posting some codes would help us to understand what you wanna do.

Comment: What is it you dont understand?

Comment: `how many unique values`... values of what?

Comment: how many unique values are input by the user - basically how many of the text inputs are unique. If its easier, just answer that question and ignore the rest.

Comment: You seem to have no idea what you actually want as output. You throw around with some ideas and expect people to shoot at them. *First* work out for yourself what exactly it is what you want, *then* edit your question and make it very clear what it is what you want, where to find the information that you want, and maybe we can help.

Comment: resolved thanks - easy fix - new user still learning so thanks for the consideration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* e.g.
   {
     "group a": [jQuery object with 3 master divs],
     "group b": [jQuery object with 1 master div],
     "group c": [jQuery object with 5 master divs]
   }
*/
var groups = {};

$(".master :text").each(function(i, textInput) {
    var master = $(textInput).closest(".master");
    var groupName = $(textInput).val();

    if (groups[groupName]) {
        groups[groupName] = groups[groupName].add(master);
    } else {
        groups[groupName] = master;
    }
});

// This is what you asked for
var numUniqueValues = Object.keys(groups).length;

// Now for each unique user-inputted groupName, you can access groups[groupName] to get a jQuery object of all the master divs for that group.
groups["sunshine"].css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: So did I read your mind correctly?